# Create an univocal id in Java

Tags: java

I have to create a Client in java. A client have a name, an address, a telephoneNumber and a ID that is univocal. I have implemented this in this way. I want to know if there is a better way to do this.

```
    public class Cliente {
        private String name;
        private int codeU;
        private String address;
        private int numTel;
        private int count=1;

        public Cliente(String name,int codeU,String address,int numTel){
            this.name=name;
            this.codeU=codeU+count;
            this.address=address;
            this.numTel=numTel;
            count++;
        }
        public int getCode(){
            return codiceU;
        }



    }
```

Second Class that extends Cliente:

```
    public class ClientGold extends Cliente {

    public ClientGold(String name, int codeU, String address, int numTel) {
        super(name, codeU, address, numTel);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

Comment: You could try generating the unique id in the constructor instead of passing it as an argument.. You could make it alphanumeric (like in SSNs).. Provide getters and setters for all fields

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `count` to be `static`, by this approach, all the updated values will remain the same for all `Cliente` instances you got and will be incremented.  
Otherwise, `count` will always have the same value which is '1'.

Comment: I have also another class GoldClient that extends Cliente, so how i can avoid that a Cliente and a GoldClient have the same Id? @Roey Golzarpoor

Comment: Yes, `GoldClient` have all variables from `Cliente`

Comment: Yes but in this way, it is possible that a Cliente and a GoldClient have the same id.... how i can avoid this?